# What is the meaning of "steadily"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This question was asked in a famous (more than a million candidates appear) civil services exam of India. Interpretation of the word "steadily" has caused so much confusion. Following is the question :

> Q. Consider the following statements :
>
> 1. Tax revenue as a percent of GDP of India has steadily increased in the last decade.
> 2. Fiscal deficit as a percent of GDP of India has steadily increased in the last decade.
>
> Which of the statements given- above is/are
>   correct ?
>
> (a) 1 only (b) 2 only (c) Both 1 and 2 (d) Neither 1 nor 2

Statement 2 is wrong so no confusion there. As fiscal deficit decreased in recent years.

Confusion arises for statement 1, since Tax revenue as a percentage of GDP though largely increased in the last decade, but there was a slight dip in 2008-09 (Global Crisis being one of major reason). Now should this statement be right or wrong?

What would be the best interpretation of the word "steadily" here?

So much on stake of this word here. (around 50000 people will fail to make next round due to this answer)

Comment: Is this question intended to test knowledge of the English language or of Indian economics?

Comment: Obviously knowledge of English word. Why do you think otherwise?
Did you read whole question? Particularly second last line? 
edit: Sorry, if you are genuinely curious, this was asked to check Indian economics. But I asked here to know what is correct interpretation. Isn't it right platform? I thought it would be best to ask here to settle the debate.

Comment: I did read the whole question and intended no offense, I simply thought the correct answer might depend on which they were testing for, especially since you mentioned that the reason statement 2 is wrong is because the fiscal deficit has decreased, which seems unrelated to the word "steadily."

Comment: Also, feel free to roll back my edit.  I simply adjusted the formatting a bit and changed "either" to "neither" because it seems that choice (d) implies that both options are incorrect.  If I was wrong in that assumption, it can be changed back.

Comment: Yeah, that was typo. Thank you. It was Neither originally.
And thanks for formatting too. It was helpful.

Comment: Increased **without surcease** or Increased **monotonically**.

Comment: As the AHD definition I give below shows, there is a polysemy/hypernymy (more or less precise) problem in the different but related senses of 'steadily' dictionaries allow. Most native speakers wouldn't shy from using 'steadily' if there was a very occasional hiccup.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Quite correct. The question really needs clarification to isolate the language problem involved from the economics one. // The only question pertinent to ELU is _Can the word 'steadily' still be used if there are minor deviations from uniformity?_ The title question encompasses this.

Comment: So I think, there is no consensus even in native speakers. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a typo?  (d) Either 1 **n**or 2
is not correct.  The following makes more sense:

> (d) Neither 1 nor 2
>
> Steadily - 1. In a regular and even manner. 3. In a controlled or
>   unwavering manner. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steadily)

So if there was a year within the the last ten where tax revenue declined then it wavered.

In mathematics, a series where two consecutive values were equal but the series otherwise increased can be said to be *increasing*.

*Strictly* or *monotonically* increasing says that each successive value in the series must be greater than the previous. [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746077/difference-between-increasing-and-monotone-increasing-function)

Comment: Thanks. So it makes statement 1 also wrong.

Don't you think, they could have used better word. Even after knowing the answer many candidates got it wrong then.

Comment: I would lodge a formal complaint.

Comment: Are you serious? :O
I mean, would such confusing question in your country will have this much consequence?
By the way, I'm talking about this exam : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Services_Examination#Process 
Usually ~1 Million students appear.

Comment: But different dictionaries better reflect the pragmatics of the situation. Most people would be prepared to accept that the sequence 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,8,9 increases 'steadily', and even that a bank balance of $300, 320, 350, 382, 410, 408, 450, 490 is 'increasing steadily'. This is reflected and licensed by [AHD's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steadily) << _steady_ ...  3. Free **or almost free** from change, **variation**, or fluctuation; uniform: a steady increase in value; a steady breeze. >> (bolding mine) So 'steadily' is less well-defined than 'monotonically'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that we are in violent agreement. :-)

Comment: But you assume only one of the conflicting definitions of 'steadily' to be acceptable. For both the sequences I give as examples, the correct answer to the question 'Is this a steady increase?' depends on the definition being used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Something that suddenly decreases is neither increasing "regular and even" nor "controlled or unwavering".

Comment: But you are arbitrarily selecting one of the two conflicting usages that are being talked about. 'Regular bowel motions' is never used to mean that a person goes at 9am, 1pm, 5pm and 7pm say precisely. In 'Hunting Trips of a Ranchman and The Wilderness Hunter' _  Theodore Roosevelt, one finds '... they travelled steadily, with only occasional short halts ...' and not '... they would have been travelling steadily were it not for occasional short halts ...'. Pragmatics trumps precision in all but the most rigorous of registers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It violates both. I just mentioned the last because, sorry, I thought the other was obvious. Reread my comment above.